# A difficult circle theorem

Tags: geometry

In the given figure, $BH\perp AD$, $DC\perp AB$, $AF\perp BD$ and $DE=EB$ then prove that $AG$ is the diameter of the circle.

[image]

I guess that the figure is incomplete but I have drawn exactly the same what is given in my book.

My attempt

$\angle AHB=90$ and $\angle ACD=90$.
Let $BH$ and $CD$ intersects at $P$. Then, $\ ACPH$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

I couldn't go any further from here. please help me to complete this.

Comment: What exactly is the point $F$ then? And if $AE$ is the perpendicular bisector of $BD$, then $AE$ passes through the center, so all you have to prove is that $G$ lies on $AE$.

Comment: It has not been defined in the question.

Comment: May be you should check your question AND the diagram provided.

Comment: From the given condition it seems that AE is the perpendicular bisector of BD but A,E has not been joined in the question.

Comment: I guess that the question should be $AF\perp BD$, not $AE\perp BD$. But I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think that it should be $AF \perp BD$, instead of $AE \perp BD$. Let $P$ be the orthocenter, the intersectin of $BH,DC,AF$. Then we have that $DGBP$ is a parallelogram, as the two diagonales intersect at their midpoints.

Now we have that: $\angle DAB + \angle DGB = \angle DAB + \angle DPB = \angle DAB + 180^{\circ} - \angle BDC - \angle DBH$
$ = \angle DAB + 180^{\circ} - 90^{\circ} + \angle ABD - 90^{\circ} + \angle BDA = \angle DAB + \angle ABD + \angle BDA = 180^{\circ}$. Therefore $G$ lies on the circumcircle of $\triangle ABD$. But now we have that $GB \parallel DC$ from $DGBP$, so $GB \perp AB$. As $G$ is on the circumcircle we must have that $AG$ is the diameter.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is orthocenter?

Comment: @user354073 The intersection of the altitudes in a triangle. The altidute is the perpendicular lines from a vertex to the opposite side.

Comment: how is $GE=EP$?

Comment: @user354073 Isn't that how you define $G$? Or am I wrong? How is $G$ defined?

Comment: I couldn't get that. Could you please put it simply?

Comment: @user354073 How is $G$ defined? What's $G$ in the picture?

Comment: That's a point on the circumference of the circle. Is it?

Comment: @user354073 It's not just a random point on the circumference.

Comment: Stefan4024, Then what's more about that point?

Comment: @user354073 From the diagram I would say that it's the intersection of $PE$ with the circumcircle or the reflection of $P$ over $E$. In any case my proof takes care of the two possibilities.

Comment: what is a circumcircle?

Comment: @user354073 I guess you can google that. BTW it's the unique circle on which three points lie.

Comment: Stefan4024, But I couldn't still get the exact reason behind $E$ being the mid point of $GP$. Could you please tell me the exact reason?

Comment: @user354073 Reflect $P$ over $E$ and let it be $G'$. Then from my answer we have that $G'$ lies on the circumcircle, meaning that it's the intersection of $PE$ and the circumcircle. So infact $G \equiv G'$.

Comment: through which three points does circumcircle pass?

Comment: @user354073 The trianlge ADB

Comment: could you please provide me a figure with all these constructions? It would be helpful for me

Comment: @user354073 The diagram you have posted is quite good for this construction.

Comment: I mean along with the constructions given in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let us compute using complex numbers. There is no loss of generality in assuming that the circum center is the origin and the circum radius is 1. Let $z_1, z_2, z_3$ be the complex numbers representing the vertices of the triangle. Then the orthocenter is $z_1+z_2+z_3$. The point $E$ is $\dfrac{z_2+z_3}{2}$. If $g$ represents the point $G$, then complex slope of $GK$ is same as complex slope of $KE$ where $K$ is the orthocenter. Thus
\begin{align*}
\frac{z_1+z_2+z_3-g}{\bar{z_1}+\bar{z_2}+\bar{z_3}-\bar{g}} &= \frac{z_1+z_2+z_3-\frac{z_2+z_3}{2}}{\bar{z_1}+\bar{z_2}+\bar{z_3}-\frac{\bar{z_2}+\bar{z_3}}{2}} = \frac{2z_1+z_2+z_3}{2\bar{z_1}+\bar{z_2}+\bar{z_3}}
\end{align*}
Clearly, $g = -z_1$ satisfies the above and hence $G$ is diametrically opposite to $A$.

Comment: Muralidharan, How is orthocenter $z_1+z_2+z_3$?

Comment: This uses the concept of complex slopes. If $z_1, z_2$ are complex numbers, then the slope is defined as $\frac{z_1-z_2}{\bar{z_1}-\bar{z_2}}$. Two lines are perpendicular if the sum of their slopes is zero, Now, the slope of $BC$ is $-z_2z_3$ (under the assumption that the circum circle is unit circle centered at the origin). If $H$ is given by $h=z_1+z_2+z_3$, then slope of $HA$ is $z_2z_3$ and hence $HA$ is perpendicular to $BC$. Similarly, we show $HB$ perpendicular to $CA$ and hence $H(z_1+z_2+z_3)$ is the orthocenter. For more details, see Titu Andreescu, Complex Numbers A to Z.